# How to increase the number of Icons in Material-UI React

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, material-ui, icons

I have a number of people that I get from API. The namber is always different. And I need to show the number of people with the help of **PersonIcon**. If there are 2 people, I need to show 2 icons.
I use **for-loop**. It counts, but displays **[object Object][object Object].** How to rewrite it correctly?

```
let participants = <PersonIcon />;
  for (let i = 1; i < activity.participants; i++) {
    participants += <PersonIcon />;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an Array:

```
let participants = [<PersonIcon />];
  for (let i = 1; i < activity.participants; i++) {
    participants.push(<PersonIcon />);
  }
```

A more elegant way to achieve the same without loop would be

```
let participants = Array.from(new Array(activity.participants), () => <PersonIcon />)
```